# How can I animate the indicator when data is fetching from service in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, uiactivityindicatorview

My requirement is when data is retrieving from JSON i need to display the activity indicator ,but data retrieving is performing in one method only.that means for example when i click on button then it retrieves the data from JSON and display in table view that table view is present in another view controller.
Here my situation is when user click on button i need to retrieve the data and navigates to the next view.when data is retrieving i need to display the activity indicator.

```
-(void)searchBtnActn {

    [self.webViewActivityIndicator setHidden:NO];

    [self.view addSubview:webViewActivityIndicator];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webViewActivityIndicator];

    [webViewActivityIndicator startAnimating];

    if ([textField.text intValue] > 0)
    {
        AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        sharedDelegate.textFldData = textField.text;

        DealerLocationMapViewController *dealerLocationObj = [[DealerLocationMapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DealerLocationMapViewController" bundle:nil];

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(
                                                       DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
             [dealerLocationObj searchBtnmethod:textField.text];

              [webViewActivityIndicator performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    });

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dealerLocationObj animated:YES];
    [dealerLocationObj release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to make some assumptions here being that your method names are not very clear to me.

Looking at:

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    [dealerLocationObj searchBtnmethod:textField.text];

    [webViewActivityIndicator performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

It seems to be that `searchBtnmethod:` is likely the method that is making the web-service call and you want it to run asynchronously which is why you have it in a `dispatch_async` block.

If that is the case you have some things out of order.

You are correct to use an async block for this method if it is a synchronous call to the web service as you do not want to block the main thread. The issue though is that you are immediately calling

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dealerLocationObj animated:YES];
```

After the block is dispatched, meaning that your view is being pushed before your web service call finishes, and hence the reason you are not seeing your activity indicator animate for the duration of the web service call.

Restructure your code to look like this, that is if my assumption was correct...

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    [dealerLocationObj searchBtnmethod:textField.text];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [webViewActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dealerLocationObj animated:YES];
    });
});
```

This will cause a block to be dispatched on the main queue that stops the activity indicator and pushes the `dealerLocationObj` view controller once the `searchBtnmethod:` finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to share your calls to `ActivityIndicator` between two classes.

There are already good projects for this feature. You should try them instead of reinventing it. They are good and used across many applications (AppStore Approved Apps).

`MBProgressHUD` & `SVProgressHUD` are good one.

Example for [`SVProgressHUD`](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD):

1. Add `SVProgressHUD.h` & `SVProgressHUD.m` in your project.
2. Then when you want to display it, call `[SVProgressHUD
   showWithStatus:@"Updating..." maskType:2];` (In your case, your showing it at right place)
3. To dismiss it, use `[SVProgressHUD dismiss];`  (In your case, may be next view controller's `viewDidAppear`)

And you are done.